# Add custom tooltips to already created chart without creating a new chart

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts

So, in google apps scripts I need to take an already created chart and edit it to add custom tooltips.  Every solution I can find requires the creation of a new chart, which doesn't work as the chart needs to be the same one as its been published to a website too.

I had hoped to do it the same way you edit the colors of a chart but don't seem to be able to that way either.

Basic code layout

```
function AddTooltips(charts, ranges, tooltips, sheet)
{
  for(i = 0; i < charts.length; i++)
  {
    var chart = charts[i]
    if(chart.getRanges()[0].getA1Notation() == ranges[i])
    {
      //CODE HERE
    }

  }
}
```

For reference, the way to edit colors on a bar chart would be to have the CODE HERE section say

```
.setOption('series.0.items.0.color', '#00FF00')
.setOption(...)
...
.build()
sheet.updateChart(chart)
```

Comment: I don't even see how you can apply a tooltip to a Google Sheet Chart?

Comment: That seems to be my issue too.  The issue Im having is that to embed a chart into a google site, you have to use an embedded chart from google sheets. But to add custom tooltips, you cannot use an embedded chart from google sheets.  Any ideas on how to get around that?

Comment: Now you lost me.  You want to embed a Google Sheet Chart into another site?  How using HTML?

Comment: Im using Google Sites to host the site.  It has a native way to embed a google sheets chart into it

Comment: What type of chart are you using? Can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output?

Comment: Its just a regular column chart and I'm currently just using dummy data anyways to try to get it working before I bother making the real full thing, so there isn't really anything real to show you an example with?

Comment: This is a feature limitation and a [request](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/3/issues/36758772) has already been submitted in the Google Issue Tracker where you can vote for it.